# How do I buy the full version of xBox games?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I wanted to try Forza 4 so I downloaded the demo, but now when I go to the overview screen it only gives me the options "rate", "free demo" and "pin to home". How do I buy the full version?

Comment: I believe this is getting down voted due to the poor grammar used in the question, making it quite unreadable and hard to understand.

Comment: It's also getting downvoted because it's missing information. The answer will be heavily dependent on the game in question, which isn't specified.

Comment: Ah true. But before his question was completely unreadable, and no-one was leaving a comment saying why. Isn't purchasing a game on Live exactly the same no matter what the game?

Comment: Sorry for my sucky grammer, and the game demo that I had downloaded was forza motorsport 4, so whenever I go into the forza 4 overview screen, the only options that I'm given are free demo,rate and pin to home and I only have the demo.

Comment: You must purchase the disc of this title in order to own the full game.

Answer (score 2):

Just because you download a demo doesn't mean that games are readily available for download. Depending on the game you may have to buy a physical copy. I can only speculate but If you cannot find a "Purchase" icon you will not be able to purchase this game. When you are about to launch the title press "X" and then you will be brought to Game Details and at this area you will be able to know whether or not you may purchase this title online.

Answer (score 0):

Go to where you downloaded the Demo and there should be an option to purchase the game. As cole stated, it may only be a demo of a "disc only" game. So although they have a demo available, you may actually have to go out and purchase the game from your local game store.